# Recognizing and Clicking Alert with RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm having some difficulty with an alert I receive during a for loop. Effectively, I can't figure out how to recognize the alert when it comes up and then close it. So far, I've tried this:

```
if (is.character(mybrowser$getAlertText()) == TRUE) {
    mybrowser$acceptAlert
    }
```

I got it to recognize the alert text once, but when I try to use that in the if statement above it doesn't work. For reference, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHdcP.png) is what the alert looks like (I'm using Windows 10, I know, I know).

UPDATE: I tried using a `try` function and it still won't close the alert but hangs instead. When I stop the program and attempt to close the alert in the console with `mybrowser$acceptAlert()`, it won't recognize the alert and hangs as well. `mybrowser$switchToWindow(window)` hangs as well. The page appears to be loading while the alert appears. I don't know if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried, for the moment, having it, say, loop for 1 minute, and every 5 or 10 seconds do `message(mybrowser$getAlertText())` and `message(is.character(mybrowser$getAlertText()))` to see what it thinks those values are? And then you can watch the console and the browser and see what's going on?

Comment: Also, does `mybrowser$acceptAlert` need parentheses at the end: `mybrowser$acceptAlert()`?

Comment: @Benjamin The parentheses after don't affect it. Ultimately the problem seems to be that I can't get it to recognize the condition on the if statement. I can't use the method you use because the alert only pops up sometimes.

Comment: what if you used `mybrowser$executeScript("alert('Hello world');")`?

Comment: (you might need to add `javascript:` before the `alert`.)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you mentioned you've tried `try` function but alert still be there sometimes. You can try `try(mybrowser$acceptAlert(), silent = TRUE)` to handle error message instead of detecting your browser receiving an alert or not.

If alert happened, `acceptAlert()` function would be equivalent to clicking the OK button. If not, `try()` function would store error messages and handle it.